# Why does my sign in function only work for one user in my CSV file with usernames and passwords?

Tags: java

I have a csv file that holds all the customers and admins of my car dealership and one of the pieces of information is a username and password. I have a sign in function where the user inputs their username and password and I use a for loop to see if the user is typing the correct credentials. I tried signing into one of my accounts which worked. However, I tried to sign into any other account and it doesnt work the same way. Below is the sign in function.

```
private static void signIn(CarDealership carDealership, Scanner scnr, ArrayList<Customer> customerList, Car carInUse) //method used to sign in
    {
        String userNameAttempt;
        String passWordAttempt;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter username:");
            userNameAttempt = scnr.next();
            for (Customer customerU : carDealership.getCustomerList()) {
                if (customerU.getUserName().equals(userNameAttempt)) {
                    System.out.println("Enter password:");
                    passWordAttempt = scnr.next();
                    if (customerU.getPassWord().equals(passWordAttempt)) {
                        System.out.println("Welcome " + customerU.getFullName());
                        if (customerU instanceof Admin) {
                            Customer customerInUse = customerU;
                            adminMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
                        }
                        Customer customerInUse = customerU;
                        customerMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
                    }
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("password is incorrect. ");
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("username does not exist. ");
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "Would you like to retry?(1) register yourself?(2) or go back?(3) ");
            int input = scnr.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
                case 1 -> {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                    signIn(carDealership, scnr, customerList, carInUse);
                    break;
                }
                case 2 -> {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                    registerCustomer(carDealership, scnr, customerList, carInUse);
                    break;
                }
                case 3 -> {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                    beginningSite(carDealership, scnr, customerList, carInUse);
                    break;
                }
                default -> {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I will say that maybe the reason one of the customers works while the others doesnt is because its the first user in the csv file. How do I make it do the for loop checks every user then throws the exceptions?

I did try moving the throws higher but it just made the password throw work before even asking the user for their password.

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("username does not exist. ");` is been called from within the `for-loop` looping over the customer information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few thing to consider with your code.

Here is the *customerU* *for-loop*.

```java
for (Customer customerU : carDealership.getCustomerList()) {
    if (customerU.getUserName().equals(userNameAttempt)) {
        System.out.println("Enter password:");
        passWordAttempt = scnr.next();
        if (customerU.getPassWord().equals(passWordAttempt)) {
            System.out.println("Welcome " + customerU.getFullName());
            if (customerU instanceof Admin) {
                Customer customerInUse = customerU;
                adminMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
            }
            Customer customerInUse = customerU;
            customerMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("password is incorrect. ");
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("username does not exist. ");
}
```

Your first *if-conitional* statement is the following.

```java
if (customerU.getUserName().equals(userNameAttempt))
```

Which, if not met, will skip directly to your throw for *IllegalArgumentException*.
And, at that rate, even if the *if-conditional* was met, upon exit of the code block, the *exception* would be thrown.

```java
throw new IllegalArgumentException("username does not exist. ");
```

Thus, if the first *Customer* within *carDealership.getCustomerList()* does not match *userNameAttempt*, the *exception* will be thrown.

I recommend re-ordering your code, as follows.

We'll need to capture whether the *userNameAttempt* was found or not.
So, I've added a *boolean* value, named *"found"*, that we'll assign as *true* when the *if-conditional* is met.

I then placed it's accompanying *IllegalArgumentException* outside of the *for-loop*, under the condition that *found == false*— which can also be written as, *!found*.

Furthermore, I inverted the *if-conditional* for the *passWordAttempt* evaluation.
Thus, having it throw the *exception* if the password is not a match.
Therefore, any code after would be under the condition that the password *was* a match.

I then placed a *break* keyword within the conditional scope, to exit the *for-loop*—since subsequent iterations would be erroneous.

And, finally, you need to create a distinction between whether *customerU* is an instance of *Admin* or not.
So, the *if-conditional* here now includes an *else* block.

Feel free to provide feedback, as I cannot run the code.

```java
boolean found = false;
for (Customer customerU : carDealership.getCustomerList()) {
    if (customerU.getUserName().equals(userNameAttempt)) {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Enter password:");
        passWordAttempt = scnr.next();
        if (!customerU.getPassWord().equals(passWordAttempt))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("password is incorrect. ");
        System.out.println("Welcome " + customerU.getFullName());
        Customer customerInUse = customerU;
        if (customerU instanceof Admin) {
            adminMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
        } else {
            customerMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
        }
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) throw new IllegalArgumentException("username does not exist. ");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make it do the for loop checks every user then throws the exceptions?

Maybe something like:

```
//  Find the Customer

Customer customerInUse = null;

for (Customer customerU : carDealership.getCustomerList()) {
    if (customerU.getUserName().equals(userNameAttempt)) {
         customerInUse = customerU;
         break;
    }
 }

if (customerInUse == null)
   // throw the Exception

//  prompt and validate the password

System.out.println("Enter password:");
passWordAttempt = scnr.next();

if (!customerInUse.getPassWord().equals(passWordAttempt))
    // throw the Exception

//  valid sign in, display the appropriate menu

if (customerInUse instanceof Admin)
    adminMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
else    
    customerMainMenu(carDealership, scnr, customerInUse, customerList, carInUse);
```